# how to calculate the confidence of a softmax layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, confidence-interval, softmax

I am working on a multi-class computer vision classification task and using a CNN with FC layers stacked on top using softmax activation, the problem is that lets say im classifying animals categories, if i predicted what a rock image is it will return a high probability for the most similar category of animals due to using softmax activation that returns a probabilistic distribution compressed between 0 and 1. what can i use to determine the confidence of my models probability output to say whether i can rely on these probabilities or not.

PS:I dont want to add a no_label class

Is it possible using keras functional api to have 2 outputs of the model the pre_softmax and the softmax output without updating the weights according to a linear activation which is the pre_softmax layer since the training would be affected

Comment: If you try to predict an image that doesn't have a rock, and your `softmax` layer has four neurons, wouldn't `no_rock` be closer to an array similar to `[.25, .25, .25, .25]`? You could also maybe have a model that has a `sigmoid` output layer, then based on it's value, continue to the `softmax` layer using previous data?

Comment: The problem i am working on is to do one model with multiple outputs  instead of two models where the first output can be the softmax probabilities and the second output is the confidence

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible using keras functional api to have 2 outputs of the model the pre_softmax and the softmax output without updating the weights according to a linear activation which is the pre_softmax layer since the training would be affected

Yes. You can do it like this

```
input = tf.keras.layers.Input((128,128,3))

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,3)(input)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128)(x)

non_softmax_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(x)
softmax_output = tf.keras.layers.Softmax()(non_softmax_output)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input,outputs=[non_softmax_output,softmax_output])

model.summary()
>>>
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_3 (InputLayer)        [(None, 128, 128, 3)]     0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 126, 126, 32)      896       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 63, 63, 32)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 flatten_1 (Flatten)         (None, 127008)            0         
                                                                 
 dense_23 (Dense)            (None, 128)               16257152  
                                                                 
 dense_24 (Dense)            (None, 10)                1290      
                                                                 
 softmax (Softmax)           (None, 10)                0         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 16,259,338
Trainable params: 16,259,338
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The easier alternative is to just work with the predictions from the softmax layer. You don't gather much from the linear layer without the activation. Those weights by themselves do not mean much. You could instead define a function outside the model that changes the predictions based on some threshold value

Assume you define only 1 output in the above model with a softmax layer. You can define a function like this to get predictions based on some threshold value you choose

```
def modify_predict(test_images,threshold):
  predictions = model.predict(test_images)
  
  max_values = np.max(predictions,axis=1)
  labels = np.argmax(predictions,axis=1)

  new_predictions = np.where(max_values > threshold, labels, 999) #You can use any indicator here instead of 999 for your no_label class
  
  return new_predictions
```

Answer (score 1):

On the first part of your question, the only way you can know how your
model will behave on non-animal pictures is by having non-animal pictures
in your data.

There are two options

The first is to include non-animal pictures in the training set (and dev and test sets), and to train the model to distinguish between animal / non-animal.
You could either build a separate binary classification model to distinguish animal/non-animal (as alrady suggesetd in comments), or you could integrate it into one model by having a
'non-animal' class. (Although I recognise you indicate this last option is
not something you want to do).

The second is to include non-animal pictures in the dev and test sets, but not in the training set. You can't then train the model to distinguish between animal and non-animal, but you can at least measure how it behaves on
non-animal pictures, and perhaps create some sort of heuristic for selecting only some of your model's predictions. This seems like a worse option to me, even though it's generally accepted that dev and test sets *can* come from a different distribution to the training set. It's something one might do if there were only a small number of non-animal pictures available, but that surely can't be the case here.

There is, for example, a large labelled image database
available at https://www.image-net.org/index.php

Comment: The second option sounds more likely to produce a model that works, the main issue I see is the definition of "non-animal" compared to the other classes (classes of animals) is *very* vague. In the universe domain, OP would need the "no animals" class to train on `universe - [animal classes]`, which is anything not an animal. I think the more feasible solution is OP processing prediction values based on a threshold and determining if the model finds *any* animal. I'd at least start assuming that close to randomly guessing is a good indicator of `no_animal` but could be a poorly trained model.

Comment: Or if going with the first option, OP would definitely need a submodel to classify animal and non-animal, but can already see that doing option one involves doing option two already.